# error in configure oracle db to Quartz.net scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, wcf, quartz.net

I am new to the forum and also learning to build Quartz.Net for one of the business needs. The requirement is to have Quartz running as a windows service and the scheduling happens via a WCF service which interacts with a Asp.Net website. All the house keeping of Jobs related activities will be handled via this WCF service making calls to quartz windows service. What I have achieved is this model works perfectly fine when I am using RAMJobStore but when I am using AdoJobStore for Oracle DB i do not see the relevant tables getting updated with JOb Details and triggers. I have downloaded the Quartz.net server and installed it as windows service without making any changes to its code.

I have changed the implementation as suggested but now i am getting the error as below:

**Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'QuartzDB': System.ArgumentException: '"Data Source' is an invalid connection string attribute**

**[EDITED]:**
The edited Config of quartz server is as below:

```
quartz.scheduler.instanceName = ServerScheduler
    quartz.scheduler.instanceId = "AUTO

    # configure thread pool info
    quartz.threadPool.type = Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz
    quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
    quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = Normal

    quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
    quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
    quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
    quartz.jobStore.clustered = true
    quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.OracleDelegate, Quartz
    quartz.jobStore.dataSource = QuartzDB
    quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
    quartz.dataSource.QuartzDB.connectionString = "Data Source=quartzdb;User Id=XXXX;Password=YYYY";
    quartz.dataSource.QuartzDB.provider = OracleODP-20

    # export this server to remoting context
    quartz.scheduler.exporter.type = Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz
    quartz.scheduler.exporter.port = 555
    quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName = QuartzScheduler
    quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType = tcp
    quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName = httpQuartz
```

Below is the [Edited] GetScheduler implementation at the WCF service level:

private static IScheduler GetScheduler()
            {
                try
                {
                  var properties = new NameValueCollection();

```
         properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteClient"; 
         properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "0"; 
         properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
         properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", "localhost", "555",
                                                                             "QuartzScheduler");
                // Get a reference to the scheduler
                var sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);

                return sf.GetScheduler();
```

}

The CreateJob and Trigger as defined in WCF service as below:

```
public string ScheduleJob<T>(string jobName, string jobGroup, string triggerName, string triggerGroup) where T : IJob
        {
            try
            {
                var scheduler = GetScheduler();
                if (scheduler != null)
                {
                    var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, jobGroup);
                    var job = JobBuilder.Create<T>()
                        .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                        //.StoreDurably()
                        //.RequestRecovery(true)
                        .Build();

                    ICronTrigger triggerObject = CreateCronTrigger(triggerName, triggerGroup);
                    if (triggerObject != null)
                    {
                        // Validate that the job doesn't already exists
                        //if (scheduler.CheckExists(new JobKey(jobKey)))
                        //{
                        //    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, triggerObject);
                        //}
                        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, triggerObject);
                        //scheduler.Start();

                        return "SUCCESS";
                    }
                    _log.FatalFormat("{0}Trigger could not be instantiated", Environment.NewLine);
                    return "FAILURE";
                }
                _log.FatalFormat("{0}Scheduler could not be instantiated", Environment.NewLine);
                return "FAILURE";
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.FatalFormat("{0}Job could not be scheduled", Environment.NewLine);
                return "FAILURE";
            }
        }

        public ICronTrigger CreateCronTrigger(string triggerName, string triggerGroup)
        {
            try
            {
                var trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroup)
                    .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *") // Queues the job every minute
                    .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
                    .WithPriority(1)
                    .Build();

                return trigger;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.FatalFormat("{0}Cron trigger could not be created", Environment.NewLine);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas why I am not able to connect to Oracle. The same credentials work fine when i connect via sqlplus.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to set on the WCF service are the following properties:

```
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteClient"; 
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true"; 
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "0"; 
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = address;
```

Remove all of the other ones from the "client".

Comment: That's correct. The Quartz server is the only one that needs to connect to the database. Your client will connect to the Quartz server over remoting.

Comment: I have updated my question and quartz.config also but now the error is related to Oracle Db connection. any inputs on that?